# How to delete replication slot in postgres 9.4

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.4

I have replication slot which I want to delete but when I do delete I got an error that I can't delete from view. Any ideas?

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_replication_slots ;
  slot_name   |    plugin    | slot_type | datoid | database | active | xmin | catalog_xmin | restart_lsn
--------------+--------------+-----------+--------+----------+--------+------+--------------+-------------
 bottledwater | bottledwater | logical   |  12141 | postgres | t      |      |       374036 | E/FE8D9010
(1 row)

postgres=# delete from pg_replication_slots;
ERROR:  cannot delete from view "pg_replication_slots"
DETAIL:  Views that do not select from a single table or view are not automatically updatable.
HINT:  To enable deleting from the view, provide an INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger or an unconditional ON DELETE DO INSTEAD rule.
postgres=#
```

Comment: I found command pg_drop_replication_slot(slot_name name) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-REPLICATION but when I do postgres=# select * from pg_drop_replication_slot('bottledwater'); I got ERROR:  replication slot "bottledwater" is already active

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Use `pg_drop_replication_slot`:

```
select pg_drop_replication_slot('bottledwater');
```

See [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-REPLICATION) and [this blog](http://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-replication-phydical-slots/).

The replication slot must be inactive, i.e. no active connections. So if there's a streaming replica using the slot you must stop the streaming replica. Or you can change its `recovery.conf` so it doesn't use a slot anymore and restart it.

Comment: humm... the link to the blog appears to be no more.

Comment: The blog post can now be found here: http://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-replication-phydical-slots/

Comment: I cant drop on the primary too... the error is that ERROR:  replication slot does not exist select * from pg_replication_slots returns nothing.

Answer (score 31):

As a complement to the accepted answer, I'd like to mention that following command will not fail in case the slot does not exist (this was useful for me because I scripted that).

```
select pg_drop_replication_slot(slot_name) from pg_replication_slots where slot_name = 'bottledwater';
```